# Is it possible to pass a <param /> from struts.xml as hidden parameter?

Tags: java, struts2

I wondered if it is possible to pass a hidden parameter to an action defining it inside `struts.xml`. I've read the `struts.xml`Document Type Definition [**HERE**](http://struts.apache.org/docs/strutsxml-examples.html) and it seems that it's not supported.

I need to pass an user's name and surname from an action to another and I don't want this two parameters to appear on the URL (I seek a `POST` request but from `struts.xml` I only know how to send `GET` ones).

**Another option** would be to send them programmatically form my action's code, but I can't use any `<s:form/>` as I'm not calling it from any `JSP`, so it has to be done straight from the action's java code.

My current `struts.xml` action code looks like this (parameters **showing** on URL):

```xml
<action name="myAction" 
  class="path.to.my.action.class"
  method="doSomething">
    <param name="name">${name}</param>
    <param name="surname">${surname}</param>
  <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**EDIT - Clarifying my question:**

I want to archieve the same thing you can archieve using a `<s:form/>`with hidden parameters like this:

```xml
<s:form theme="simple" action="myAction">
 <s:hidden name="name"/>
 <s:hidden name="surname"/>
 <s:submit value="%{'Submit'}"/>
</s:form>
```

That would trigger `myAction` and pass through the two parameters, `name`and `surname`but the user would not be able to see those parameters.

Comment: What do you mean by hidden parameter?

Comment: @RomanC please see updated question. I'm doing it this way and not using the `<s:form />` because I don't have a JSP for this `myAction`. I'm creating a kind of edit panel so that it has it's own JSP, but when user clicks the save button (`submit`) I trigger another action which saves the data and redirects to a list... so that's why I can't use the `<s:form />` tag. The code I posted on the question is a mere example and not my "real" code as the action is a little more complex because I have a redirection inside it, I just wanted to ask a simple question

Comment: If you don't want to use a form you don't need to use a hidden fields. Set the scope of the properties to the action and reuse it in another.

Comment: I think I don't fully understand what you mean. I just wanted to know if it is possible to pass those parameters from `struts.xml` but not visible to the user. I know this can be archieved from many other ways, but I want to emphasize in doing it from `struts.xml`

Comment: In the `struts.xml` you can use parameters in the result.

Comment: What's the usecase for needing to do this?

Comment: @DaveNewton The user sees a list grid (`action1`) and clicks a button to input some info in a new JSP (`action2` is called to render and show this JSP page), then clicks submit to save the data entered when finished (`action3` when submit is clicked), and is redirected back to action1. I need to pass two parameters from 3 to 1 and I can only think in doing it from `struts.xml` as action3 doesn't render a new JSP page (so I can't use the form tag) and also I don't know how to pass them from action3 to action1 if they are passed from action2 to action3.. It's a bit twisty to understand :)